# Font-Awesome not working inside DIV tag

Tags: html, font-awesome

I can't figure this out... For some reason font awesome will not render inside a `<DIV>` tag on my page.  When I remove the `<DIV>` tag, the font awesome icon shows fine.  I stripped out the class, style, id from the DIV tag and it still happens. Has anyone seen this before? I'm sure it has to be an issue with my code, but I can't figure it out.

Note that the font awesome icons work fine when input outside the particular `<DIV>` tag (below and above the tag).

```
<div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 50px; padding-top: 20px;">
    <fieldset class="group-select" id="supercheckout-fieldset">
        <div id="form_disable" style="background: #e0ffbb; opacity:0.1; z-index:99999; position: absolute;"></div>
        <div id="supercheckout-columnleft" class="supercheckout-threecolumns supercheckout-container supercheckout-skin-generic">
```

I'm getting closer... I removed the following tag and it works fine.

```
<fieldset class="group-select" id="supercheckout-fieldset">
```

Here is the CSS that's impacting the font awesome icons...

```
#supercheckout-fieldset div *,
color :#000000;
line-height: none;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-transform : none;
hanging-punctuation: none;
text-align-last: none;
text-justify: none;
text-overflow: none;
text-shadow: none;
text-wrap: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style :none;
font-family :Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
border: none;
border-image: none;
border-radius: 0px;
max-width:none;
min-width:0px;
box-shadow: none;
background :none;
background-image: none;
background-color: none;
opacity: 1;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
width: auto;}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Here is the sniplet of code:

<div  class="container" style="padding-bottom: 50px; padding-top: 20px;">  
<fieldset class="group-select" id="supercheckout-fieldset">
    <div id="form_disable" style="background: #e0ffbb; opacity:0.1; z-index:99999; position: absolute;"></div>
    <div id="supercheckout-columnleft" class="supercheckout-threecolumns supercheckout-container supercheckout-skin-generic">

Comment: Any font awesome icons inside the last DIV tag above do not show up. Any font awesome icons outside the above DIV tag show up fine. I stripped down the tag to just <DIV> and for some reason the icons still do not show. Makes no sense, my page code must have an issue somewhere.

Comment: First, code goes in questions and answers, not in comments. I've moved it for you.  Then, please, put CSS in a style tag. It's a mess to work with and a mess to interpret on our end. You'll get much better help at SO.

Comment: Sorry first time using this. I've updated my original post, getting closer to solving.

Comment: You also need to post the CSS related to `.group-select` and `#supercheckout-fieldset`!

Comment: CSS added. I've narrowed it down to the problematic CSS. See original post for CSS.

Comment: Amateur mistake I suppose, removed the "font-family" CSS and it's working now. SOLVED.

Answer (score 2):

It's because inside `#supercheckout-fieldset div *`, you have `font-family :Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;`.

Having an ID makes this more specific than font-awesome's css which merely has a class, thus this rule overrides font-awesome's font-family declaration.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity